# Angular apps break when run in Electron

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron

I started building an Electron app and I am encountering some issues when I try to run an angular distribution inside.

For the angular app I'm using yeoman and grunt for building. If I develop the angular app with `grunt serve` and running it on localhost:9000, the Electron app can pick the application up just fine. However, if I run grunt build and I point the Electron app to the static files I get some angular errors.

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module clientApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module 
ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

In the electron app Im running a server with express and I also tried to pick run the angular app through express at localhost:8000. That didn't work either. I also tried to run another angular app that it's deployed on my server and working just fin in the browser - didn't work in Electron. Same errors on all the tries.

I also have to mention that in all cases, if I open the angular app in the browser it works fine.

This is the electron code:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 764, title: "uMaster"});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  var url = path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html");
  url = "file://" + url;
  console.log(url);

  // mainWindow.loadURL(url); ---- this is not working in Electron
  // mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:8000"); -- not working when served by express
  mainwindow.loadURL("http://localhost:9000"); // working when angular runs with grunt serve

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  /* ----------------------- */
});
```

Comment: sounds like you've missed a reference to `angular-resource.min.js`

Comment: It's not that, if modify the order of the angular modules, it will just say that the first module is not referenced and it crashes. The references is obviously there since it runs outside of electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem by initialising electron's `BrowserWindow` with `nodeIntegration: false`

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 764, title: "app", webPreferences: {"nodeIntegration":false}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. If you want to mantain node integration you can also use this code in your `index.html`, before loading any other script:

```
<script>
  window.nodeRequire = require;
  delete window.require;
  delete window.exports;
  delete window.module;
</script>
```